# Javascript split the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like this

```
"(length>10)&(length<100)"
```

And i want this

```
(,length,>,10,),&,(,length,<,100,)
```

Is it possible get with javascript split and regex.

Comment: FYI, this is called tokenising or lexing. You may want to read about lexing and lexical analysers (and lexical analyser generators).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"(length>10)&(length<100)".split( /([()><&])/ ).filter( Boolean )

["(", "length", ">", "10", ")", "&", "(", "length", "<", "100", ")"]
```

This splits at either: `(`, `)`, `>`, `<` or `&` (the "or" is thanks to the `[]` around).

Keeping the split characters is done thanks to the capture (the parentheses around the square brackets - it's ES5 though, so not supported in IE8 and below).

Finally, to remove empty strings, I use `filter( Boolean )` on the array ( ES5 too, not supported in IE8 and below either).

Answer (score 2):

```
result = subject.split(/\b|(?!\w)/);
```

This splits at boundaries between alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric characters, additionally between two non-alnum characters. You might get an empty match at the start/end of the string, so you need to discard zero-length results.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `split`, I'd go for a global `match`, which behaves more like a tokenizer:

```
var input = "(length>10)&(length<100)";
var tokens = input.match(/\d+|[a-zA-Z]\w*|[()]|[<>=&|]+/g);
```

It scans the input and matches the following patterns (in order):

```
\d+           # one ore more digits
|             # OR
[a-zA-Z]\w*   # an identifier
|             # OR
[()]          # a single opening- or closing parenthesis
|             # OR
[<>=&|]+      # one or more operators: '<=', '&', '|=', ...
```